# Minimal covering of rectangle with fixed, overlapping rectangles

Tags: computational-geometry

A finite set $R$ of fixed, axis aligned 2-D rectangles $r_i=\left\{x_{0i},y_{0i},W_i,H_i \right\}$ is given. These rectangles are potentially overlapping. Given a new axis aligned rectangle $t$, I would like to find the subset $S \subset R$ with minimum number of elements $M$ such that $t \subset \underset{i=1,\ldots,M}{\bigcup} s_i$. Is this a known computational geometry problem?

Comment: This seems to be somewhat similar to the "Knapsack problem", perhaps checking it out will be useful.

Comment: Indeed there is a family of Knapsack problems that deals with geometric entities, however in my problem the rectangles are fixed so they do not seem to apply directly.